# Как добавить объекты в префаб?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Ракета на сцене пускает дым . Клонируя за собой тучи дыма . Которые через 5 секунд одна за  другой исчезают .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я поставлю одну тучу дыма на сцене в качестве клона , то тучи начнут клонироваться , но через 5 секунд они все одновременно удаляться . Мне нужно чтобы тучи удалялись постепенно , а не сразу . Для этого я создал префаб тучи . Тогда все работало нормально . Но я столкнулся с проблемой что я не могу поместить объект в префаб .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Молю о помощи , а то ломаю голову уже который день .

Answer (score 0):

Префабы можно редактировать. Дважды щёлкни на префаб во вкладке Project. Откроется вкладка Hierarchy с твоим префабом. Добавь нужные компоненты и снова переключись на сцену, нажав на < слева от имени префаба.

Comment: А как перетащить если у меня открывается Hierarchy с префабом а не с другими объектами ?

Comment: Я не понимат=( Посмотри какое-нибудь видео про префабы. Это проще, чем я буду словами объяснять что да как делать.